# Integrating OpenStreetMap with React Native for Marker Placement: How?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Hey fellow developers,

I'm currently working on an application where I need to integrate a map feature using OpenStreetMap in React Native. Specifically, I'm looking to set markers on the map dynamically based on certain data points.

Ideally, I'm looking for guidance on:

How to integrate OpenStreetMap into a React Native project.

How to dynamically add markers to the map based on data points.

Any potential challenges or pitfalls to watch out for during integration.

Any insights, code snippets, or tutorials would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance for your help. Let's build better maps together!

Cheers!

I've done some research, but I'm struggling to find clear, concise resources or examples on how to achieve this. Has anyone successfully integrated OpenStreetMap into a React Native app for marker placement? If so, could you share your approach or any helpful resources?